# Sitecore Web Index Rebuild

Tags: solr

We are using  Solr 5.4 and Sitecore 8.2 we plan to do daily/Weekly Rebuild of Indexes for Web Environment through Sitecore Job or  Tasks. Can some body  suggest me what is best way to do this

Note : We are already using PublishOnSync strategy

Cheers

Comment: If you have already update index on publish, why do you need to rebuild the index?

Comment: We still need to have  full rebuild of Indexes for Web this is a Design we have closed.

Comment: Your best option is do implement an agent which will trigger the rebuild index.

Answer (score 6):

I did something similar to this not long ago to rebuild the sitemaps of 800+ sites. I used the Sitecore scheduled tasks.

### Create a task

```
namespace Sitecore.Sitemaps.Tasks
{
    class GenerateSitemaps
    {
        public void Execute(
          Sitecore.Data.Items.Item[] items,
          Sitecore.Tasks.CommandItem command,
          Sitecore.Tasks.ScheduleItem schedule)
        {
            // This is where you all your indexing code
            var sitemapService = new SitemapService();
            sitemapService.RebuildAllSitemaps();
        }

    }
}
```

### Create a command

Go to the path `/sitecore/system/Tasks/Commands/` and create a new command item. In type enter the class you created above. i.e. `Sitecore.Sitemaps.Tasks.GenerateSitemaps, Sitecore.Sitemaps`. In method enter `Execute`

### Create a schedule

Go to the item `/sitecore/system/Tasks/Schedules/` and create a new schedule. For the command, select the command item you created above. The schedule field is a little hard to understand, but it makes sense in the end. The text below I borrowed from [this](https://www.degdigital.com/insights/how-to-create-sitecore-scheduled-task/) page.

> The Schedule field can be a bit tricky. You’ll notice in my example
>   above that I have several piped values. They are defined as follows:
>
> 1. The start date in yyyyMMdd format.
> 2. The end date in yyyyMMdd format.
> 3. The days of the week that the task should be run. Each day is assigned a value: 1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, 4 = Tuesday, 8 = Wednesday,
>      16 = Thursday, 32 = Friday, and 64 = Saturday. For example to run a
>      task Monday through Friday you’d enter 62 (2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32). I
>      have my task set up to run every day (1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32 + 64 =
>      127).
> 4. The minimum interval the task is to be run in HH:mm:ss format. The example above is set to run once every 24 hours.

Thats it. Now on a schedule basis your indexing code will run.

If you need the code to rebuild an index, its pretty straight forward.

```
IndexCustodian.FullRebuild(ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("[INDEX NAME]"), true);
```